# Sonarcloud sonar.language=js is also detecting css code

Tags: sonarqube, sonarcloud

I created SonarCloud Integration for my React repository.
My `sonar-project.properties` file looks like this;

```
sonar.organization=<org_name>

sonar.projectKey=<project_key>
sonar.projectName=<project_name>

sonar.sources=.
sonar.exclusions=example/**

sonar.language=js
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

After I completed integration, I saw that SonarCloud is also getting `.css` files along with `.js` files, but I don't have any configuration to enable this. I'm only requesting my JS code to be evaluated. And a `.css` file showing bugs and because of this bug, my quality gate is failing. I couldn't understand why `.css` files are part of the process.

Is it a default behaviour? Should I exclude `.css` files as well?

Any help will be highly appreciated, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue can be found [here](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/disable-languages/41394), and the solution is simple, just exclude every CSS file:

```
sonar.exclusions = **/*.java
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I can exclude `.css` files but I couldn't understand why they are included in the first place. I wrote `sonar.language=js` so I has nothing to do with `.css` files I guess.

Comment: I believe that SonarQube's default behavior is to analyze all of the code that exists in the repo, regarding what language you set as "default".